# Why do you have to kasher kitchen counters for Pesach?

Tags: halacha, passover, kashering-kosherization

If you don't use your countertops for either kli rishon or sheine, why do [some require](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=2674) them to be kashered for Pesach?

Comment: There is a risk of chametz getting on to them and we don't do batul b'shishim for chametz.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Assuming as you said, Chametz did get on to them, wouldn't the only concern be if you would put something very hot onto the counter during Pesach?  For example if extremely hot food landed on the counter during Pesach?  Otherwise there should be no problem.  Correct?

Comment: That source doesn't say that you have to kasher them if you don't use them for hot things. -1

Answer (score 2):

[Chicago Rabbinical Council’s Guidelines to Kashering Counter tops and Stovetops for Pesach](http://www.kashrut.com/Passover/countertops/) and [Countertops](http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/Kashering_in_the_Kitchen.php#countertops) while explaining what countertops need to be kashered and how they can be kashered, also imply why they need to be kashered. Many materials are porous or can develop cracks. Other materials develop a film that needs to be cleaned (and will have been absorbed into the material over the course of the year) or hot foods can spill onto the countertops. Even if you are careful, it is possible that some time during the year, your countertop can come into contact with hot chametz (as explained in various sources and by my LOR).

As a result, it is best to treat the countertop in the same way as you treat your sink, especially in the areas near your stove top.

Comment: That only makes sense if you were to put actual food on your countertop. I would think most people use cutting boards or plates? It's like saying your chairs have to be kasher lepesach.

Comment: @Yishaq In most cases, there will turn out to be usages of the counters that allow them to ever become Chametz. Most counters, sometime during the year could have spills or splashes. The point that I am making is that unlike your chair, food splashes do occur so it is best to be extra careful when getting ready for Pesach. This is also the implications of the various sources. If you are certain that it **never** came in contact with chametz, then 'ask your LOR'.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks...it is overkill.  Even if there is a chance that hametz got on the countertop, it is highly unlikely that it was hot enough to be yad soledet bo.  And even if it were hot enough, rov tashmish would still be relevant.  Wiping down the countertop is thus sufficient.

Do not overwork.  Do not overspend.

-RavSean

Comment: please give sources. also countertop types differ. That is why they should be covered just in case.

Comment: @sabba no, that's why you should check every case and not make general rules

Comment: @shmuel no, it's relevant even according to the Rama, just not as important as to the mechabber. Even the Rama is Meikil Bedieved. Since you have no intention of putting hot food on the counter on pesach, any such use that happens would be an accident and Bedieved fine.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.
Hope to see you around!